# ZVS driver not oscillating

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, zvs

[image]
As far as i can tell i am following this circuit, although different components. However, when connected to a DC supply, both LEDs light up dimly and there is no oscillation. It appears that the drains of the MOSFETs are connected together via the inductor and the Vgs of both MOSFETs are constant.

Without the LC tank, only one LED lights up, so I assume that means the MOSFETs are indeed working. I also tested each MOSFET individually without the LC tank and they do indeed both work.

The components I am using are as follows:

MOSFETs: IRFP260N

Schottky diodes: UF4001

The resistors are normal 0603 SMD resistor, all values are as shown above

The capacitor is a MLCC, all values, are as shown above

The inductor is a toroid inductor, all values are as shown above

I am using a simple arduino UNO as the 5V power supply.

Comment: What Schottky, did you mean the `1N4148`? Those are not Schottky. At any rate, LTspice seems to [show something](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBSrJ.png). The current might be too high for the LED, but I used a random one from the database (best check the datasheet).

Comment: Would it be any different if i used the UF4001?

Comment: I don't think so, they're supposed to be ultrafast recovery. However I don't quite follow this part: "*I am using a simple arduino UNO as the 5V power supply*". Are you generating the 5 V from the uC, or from a proper power supply? It'd better be the latter, since you do need the current.

Comment: I've been using an UNO, but I'll hook up a proper power supply and update you if anyth happens

Comment: OH its oscillating, i jus removed the LEDs. Tks for all the help!